# Wordpress Create Custom Post on New User Register

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress I'm Trying to Create Custom Post on New User Register of specific user role "author"

For This I try to figure out this Code in Function.php

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_216921_company_cpt', 10, 1 );

function wpse_216921_company_cpt( $user_id )
{
    // Get user info
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles=$user_info->roles;

 if ($user_roles == 'author') {
    // Create a new post
    $user_post = array(
        'post_title'   => $user_info->nickname,
        'post_type'    => 'CustomPost', // <- change to your cpt
    );
    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );

 }

}
```

But Not Success. After I add above code no error working fine but it not triggering automatic and not creating new custom post

I simple want that whenever I add new Author / New Author Register it create one Custom Post with title as same as username. and publish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role your are checking with is not correct, `$user_info->roles` returns an array, not a string. Find the modified code below,

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_216921_company_cpt', 10, 1 );

function wpse_216921_company_cpt( $user_id )
{
    // Get user info
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_info->roles;

    // New code added 
    $this_user_role = implode(', ', $user_roles );

    if ($this_user_role == 'author') {

        // Create a new post
        $user_post = array(
            'post_title'   => $user_info->nickname,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'CustomPost', // <- change to your cpt
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dipak , Thanks you so much it's working perfectly fine... I noticed that function add new post as "draft" only.... is it possible to Publish that post?

Comment: as i'm new my reputation not allow me to upvote but thanks for your help.... by the way if you accepting freelance job please share me skype / whatsapp  for my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted to my cpt structure but no post is created, only if I comment the part relartive to role check ( I have a custom role 'attivita' with same capabilities as 'author' and it is allowed to create CPT 'attivita' - through PublishPress Capabilities plugin)...

```
 function wpse_216921_cpt( $user_id )
{
// Get user info

$user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

$user_roles = $user_info->roles;

// check user role 

$this_user_role = implode(', ', $user_roles );

if ($this_user_role == 'attivita') {

    
   // Create a new post
   
    $user_post = array(
      'post_title' =>  $user_info->user_login,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_author' => $user_id,
      'post_type' => 'attivita'        
      
 );
    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );
 }
 }
```